# Issue with appending data to a list in python

Tags: python, append, attributeerror

I'm currently in the midst of creating a "hangman" game but I can't seem to use the append function to add data to my list as it keeps on giving the error:

**

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

**

Here is my code for reference:

```
import random

name_list = ['jason', 'enrique']
current_ans = []

i = 0
while i < len(name_list[1]):
    current_ans = print("_ ", end=' ')
    i = i + 1

print("\nThis is a", len(name_list[1]), "letter word")

while True:

    if current_ans != name_list[1]:
        print('Enter a letter')
        guess = input()

        if guess in name_list[1]:
            print('Correct!')
            current_ans.append(guess)

            for letter in name_list[1]:

                if guess == letter:
                    print(str(current_ans), end=' ')

                else:
                    print('_ ', end=' ')

        else:
            print('Incorrect!')
    else:
        print('Congratulations!!! You guessed the correct word')
        break


# Cross checks input with name list & Swaps out _ with correct input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside while loop you have assign,

```
current_ans = print("_ ", end=' ')
```

It returns current_ans = None

Error occurs because you are trying to append element to None object.

```
current_ans.append(guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting

```py
    current_ans = print("_ ", end=' ')
```

You are changing `current_ans` from a list to the `print()` return which is `None`.

`print()` doesn't return anything

Comment: @Tamir that is clearly the line of code that's causing the problem. However, your statement that *print()* "only prints to screen" is misleading

Comment: Noted, updated to avoid confusion